# Strain on eyes when seeing a mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses, vision

Suppose; The strain on my eyes when seeing an object at distance `x` is `a`.
The strain on my eyes when seeing an object at distance `2x` is `b`.

Now if I see the image in the mirror (mirror is at distance `x`) what is the strain in my eye? What I actually see is my VIRTUAL image, so is the strain in my eye `a (for seeing the mirror at distance x)` OR `b (for seeing the VIRTUAL image at distance 2x)`?
And Similarly explain for lens (where image is real so the strain on eye is for seeing image I think)

[**WIKIPEDIA:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_image)
The image in a plane mirror is not magnified (that is, the image is the same size as the object) and ***appears*** to be as far behind the mirror as the object is in front of the mirror.

Light APPEARS to come from behind but not actually that's why it's called VIRTUAL IMAGE(So strain is for a distance `x (for seeing mirror) i.e 'a'`is what I understood.

Edit:-
Light is coming from the mirror, only **appears** to come the VIRTUAL Image. So strain should be for seeing the mirror.
[image]

Comment: When standing in front of the mirror, draw a dot with a marker on the mirror, you can clearly get to know the difference in strain in your eyes when seeing the dot on the mirror and your own image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lens in your eye doesn't know or care where the light is coming from. All it does is change the angle of the light passing through it. So as far as your lens is concerned the light coming from a real object at a distance $2x$ away is the same as the light coming from the virtual object at a distance $2x$ away formed by a mirror. In both cases the angles of the light rays reaching the lens are the same so they will be focussed in exactly the same way.

So the effort needed by your eye to focus is the same for a real object at $2x$ and  virtual object at $2x$.

Comment: A Virtual Image is NOT REAL right, so how is the strain for distance `2x`?

Comment: @vivian.ai the light reaching your eye from a virtual image at a distance $2x$ is the same as the light reaching your eye from a real image at $2x$ so your eye has to put in the same mount of effort to focus it onto your retina.

Comment: Even though the light exists only in front of the mirror your eye will still perceive it to be coming from 'inside' the mirror and has to accommodate for that. Your eye focuses not on the surface of the mirror. It focuses on the image 'inside the mirror's therefore the strain should be b